# Can't get django-testapp to work or create a superuser with django-norel

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm new to django-nonrel and I'm trying to get the djang0-testapp to run.

I can't even create a superuser. I am following the instructions from [here](https://www.allbuttonspressed.com/projects/djangoappengine)

I downloaded the django-testapp from [here](https://github.com/django-nonrel/django-testapp)

I placed all the required folders inside the django-testapp as the instructions tell me to do.

I notice that the settings.py  file is in the project folderalong with the manage.py file.

This is different from the normal django which has 
a project folder that has manage.py file and an inner folder
that has the settings.py file.

When I try to create a superuser I get the following error message.

```
C:\Users\laurence\Documents\GitHub\django-testapp>manage.py createsuperuser
Error: Can't find the file 'settings.py' in the directory containing 'C:\\Users\
\laurence\\Documents\\GitHub\\django-testapp\\manage.py'. It appears you've cust
omized things.
You'll have to run django-admin.py, passing it your settings module.
(If the file settings.py does indeed exist, it's causing an ImportError somehow.
```

)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `django-nonrel`.

---

Does your `settings.py` file exist?

If it does, it's probably syntactically incorrect, run `python settings.py` to identify the `SyntaxError`.

Comment: Thank you Thomas for your reply. I did have a settings.py file and it's syntax is correct. Your suggestion helped me find that I had copied the directories wrong inside the django-testapp. I had copied the outer folders over instead of the inner folders.